# Dynamically label string of Y axis scale label is not changing in chart.js (Angular-4)

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

When I'm dynamically changing the string label of scale in Y-axis using chart.js in my angular-4 code on click of any button then it will not change, it displays same value which I have declared by default.

I tried to change it by calling a function on click of my button and return dynamic value on a function call.

```
chart.options.scales.yAxes[0].scaleLabel.labelString = 'dynamic value';
```

I am expecting as when I click the  on button and call function than the label string gets changed from by default value  to the dynamic value

Comment: Which library you are using

Comment: please provide a plucker!

Comment: If you are updating something after the chart has been rendered, you need to call the update method.

Comment: I have exactly same scenario. My chart is in a loop. And each one is different from the other. Have you solved this issue? If so , then how ?